# Increment a part of URL when a button is clicked in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, use-state

I am creating a web app, which is basically an image gallery for a browser game.
The avatars are stored in the game in this format:

`https://websitelink.com/avatar/1`

`https://websitelink.com/avatar/2`

`https://websitelink.com/avatar/3`

So i want to build 2 navigation buttons, one will increment the counter, to move to next image and another one will decrement the counter to move to previous image.
I tried to use props, but since props are immutable it didn't work.

How do I approach building this web app?

Comment: Please add a snippet of the code you tried. That way others can have an idea of what you did wrong or what's missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the minimal code which may help you to understand about the `React Component`, `props` and `state`.

```js
// parent compoment
import { useState } from "react"

export const GameImageGallery = () => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
    const increaseDecrease = (state) => {
        if (state === "+") {
            setNum(num + 1)
        }
        if (state === "-") {
            setNum(num - 1)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => increaseDecrease("-")}>--</button>
            <button onClick={() => increaseDecrease("+")}>++</button>
            <Image url={`https://websitelink.com/avatar/${num}`} />
        </>
    )
}
```

```js
// child component to show image
const Image = ({ url }) => {
    return <img src={url} alt="image" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this thing,

```
const [id,setId]=useState(0);

useEffect(() => {

},[id])

const increment = () => {
    setId(id++);        
}
const decrement = () => {
    setId(id--);        
}


return(
    <button onClick={increment}>Add</button>
    <button onClick={decrement}>remove</button>
    <img url={`https://websitelink.com/avatar/${id}`} />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`useRef` is ideal to manage data persistently in a component.

Example:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
...
const App = () => {
    const links = useRef({url1Ctr : 1})
    const onBtnClick = () => {
        links.current = { url1Ctr: links.current.url1Ctr + 1}
    }
    ...
}
```